# Hardcode UTC DateTime value (12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 A.D. (C.E.), UTC) in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, utc

I have a UTC DateTime value: 12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 A.D. (C.E.), UTC

How would I hardcode this UTC DateTime value in C#

```
if (job.DateTimeValue == <UTC value>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DateTime` type has a constructor that allows you to set:

- `Year`
- `Month`
- `Day`
- `Hour`
- `Minute`
- `Second`
- `Millisecond`
- `DateTimeKind` (UTC, Local, Unspecified)

---

```
var jobMinDateValue = new DateTime(1601, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

if (job.DateTimeValue == jobMinDateValue)
{
    // ...
}
```

---

*12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 A.D. (C.E.), UTC* happens to be a special date & time on Windows... Windows represents [`FileTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.fromfiletimeutc) as the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 A.D. (C.E.) Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

That means that in `FileTime` terms the value `0` means `12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 A.D. (C.E.), UTC`

That gives you another alternative to get the same value you're looking for:

```
var jobMinDateValue = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(0);

if (job.DateTimeValue == jobMinDateValue)
{
    // ...
}
```